# IdentityServer4 Quickstart for IdentityServer as Identity/api endpoints and MVC client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

I'm running asp.net core 3.1 and IdentityServer4 following the quick start and guides.

I'm a bit lost when implementing IS end points and api endpoints in the same project.  I want the server to host IS authentication/login urls, apis and mvc client.  I want to issue bearer tokens which will be used by the IS host/mvc client and client credential clients.

I have gone through the quick starts and gotten the MVC client and the console client to authenticate with my identity server host, but when I try to use my identity server host to authenticate and then go to one of the view controllers, I just get a circular workflow back through authentication.

I believe it's because my account controller login post method isn't issuing the bearer token.  I'm thinking there's a call I need make to identity server during login to get it to set the bearer cookie.  (It's also possible I'm just missing something on my view controller to tell it it's part of the group to allow access?)

I have this in which allows the client credentials from the console app to work:

```
    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Constants.HostUrl;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
             options.Audience = "api";
        });
```

But if I remove it, then the login workflow through the host identity server works and I can access my view and api controllers.

Is there a quick start that I'm missing that shows the identity server also being the mvc client?

Thanks

Comment: the code `services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")` adds authentication for the service. This defines that incoming requests have to have json web token in the header request. There is no token check made if you remove the `AddAuthentication` and `AddJwtBearer` calls. It means that you are accessing view and api controllers but no token check is made. I can not understand your case well unfortunately. Can you please check [IdentityServer samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts) and  help me to understand what is similar to your case?

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to use my identity server host to authenticate to itself, I just get a circular workflow back through authentication.

Well, what does it mean `for itself`?
Do you try to ask for token for the service that is used to host the REST API ?

It looks like you have some kind of client (like background service whatever) and is trying to get token for that client.
Is it so?

Seems that you can use [the client credentials flow](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/Client/Program.cs) However this requires clientid and secret to be stored somewhere. [Here is some documentation](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/).

You can use Identity server's [Windows Authentication feature](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/topics/windows.html) also

Comment: Thanks for your response/question. I updated the question to try to clarify, I mean the identity server auth host/api host login workflow just goes back to login after completing its login.